# getting error when using wso2 ldap connector

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 LDAP connector for retrieving data from ldap server.so getting following error when calling my service.try to searchEntry operation.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errorMessage": "Missing 'equals'",
    "errorCode": 7000001
  }
}
```

Also I refer to [wso2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+CRUD+operations+in+LDAP#WorkingwithCRUDoperationsinLDAP-searchEntry)  for the above scenario.

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an authentication error with LDAP. Can you recheck the request you are sending and see if the credentials are correct?

Comment: thanks for reply. I checked user credentials. It's all correct. And I logged my service.it seems to be ldap connection is good. Is there any reason for this ?

Comment: this error code 7000001 can occur if we search for an entry that is not in the domain. The details for error codes are available on https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+User+Authentication+in+LDAP